# Accessing Files with .net on Linux Containers in Windows

Tags: .net, docker

I have the following simple app

```
var fileCount = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"/home/joe").Count();
Console.WriteLine($"Hello,!  There are {fileCount} files.-");
```

And a dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish HelloDocker   -c Release -o publish

FROM base AS final
COPY --from=build src/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "HelloDocker.dll"]
```

I am attempting to run this with variations of the following command based on search results.

`docker run -i test:nobase -v c:/temp:/home/joe`

but keep getting a `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException` saying that `Could not find a part of the path '/home/joe'.`

How should the correct path to `c:\temp` be shared and accessed from my app when running in a container?

Answer (score 1):

`docker run` arguments *before* the image name are docker arguments and arguments *after* the image name become a command for the container, overriding any CMD statements in the image.

A volume mapping is a docker parameter, so it needs to go before the image name like this

```
docker run -i -v c:/temp:/home/joe test:nobase
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that infornation!